# Can not retrieve likes and dislikes in youtube with the pytube module

Tags: python, pytube

I using pytube library
However, I didn't find functions for getting likes and dislikes in YouTube video
There are functions for fetching title, description, etc. but no functions for fetching channel name or number of likes
i tried this code

```
from pytube import YouTube
link = input('Enter your link:')
video = YouTube(link)
print(f"The video title is:\n{video.title} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video rating is:\n{video.rating} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video Views is:\n{video.viewcount} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video author is:\n{video.author} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video length is:\n{video.length} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video duration is:\n{video.duration} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video likes is:\n{video.likes} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video dislikes is:\n{video.dislikes} \n------------------------------")
```

```
python baba.py
Enter your link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_gXTjBZOms
The video title is:
كيفيى إضافة عناصر إلى قائمة جديد new في جميع إصدارات windows
------------------------------
The video rating is:
5.0
------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MesterPerfect\Desktop\baba.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(f"The video Views is:\n{video.viewcount} \n---------------------------
---")
AttributeError: 'YouTube' object has no attribute 'viewcount'
```

Are there solutions?

Comment: Please show us your efforts, what you tried and then if you faced any problem feel free to ask for help, will be happy to help rhen

Comment: I made the required adjustments, is this the correct system?

Comment: Is viewcount the right attribute name there? Check the documentation for the library to make sure.

Comment: I tried to verify and found nothing in the documents, so I put the question

Answer (score 2):

Try it :)

```
from pytube import YouTube
import re


like_template = r'[0-9]{1,3},?[0-9]{0,3},?[0-9]{0,3} like'
yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysSxxIqKNN0')
str_likes = re.search(like_template, str(yt.initial_data)).group(0)
likes = int(str_likes.split(' ')[0].replace(',', ''))
print(str_likes) # 2,486,532 like
print(likes) # 2486532
```

Comment: how can we get the dislike and description using pytube?

Answer (score 1):

For finding views you can use `views` method the method you are looking for is available in another module named `pafy`

```
from pytube import YouTube
link ="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_gXTjBZOms"
video = YouTube(link)
print(f"The video title is:\n{video.title} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video rating is:\n{video.rating} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video Views is:\n{video.views} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video author is:\n{video.author} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video length is:\n{video.length} \n------------------------------")
```

Also you can install `pafy` and try out from [docs](https://pypi.org/project/pafy/)

With `pafy`

```
import pafy
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_gXTjBZOms"
video = pafy.new(url)
print(f"The video title is:\n{video.title} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video rating is:\n{video.rating} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video Views is:\n{video.viewcount} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video author is:\n{video.author} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video length is:\n{video.length} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video duration is:\n{video.duration} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video likes is:\n{video.likes} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video dislikes is:\n{video.dislikes} \n------------------------------")
```

with `pyfy` and `pytube` just create separate instance from it used according what methods are include

```
from pytube import YouTube
import pafy

link ="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_gXTjBZOms"
video = YouTube(link)
video1=pafy.new(link)

# Git video info using pytube
print(f"The video title is:\n{video.title} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video rating is:\n{video.rating} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video Views is:\n{video.views} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video author is:\n{video.author} \n------------------------------")

# Git video info using pafy
print(f"The video duration is:\n{video1.duration} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video likes is:\n{video1.likes} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video dislikes is:\n{video1.dislikes} \n------------------------------")
```

Comment: Thanks
Can i use pytube and pafy together
But I want pytube and pafy output in single output

Comment: yes you can import both library and you can use functionality

Comment: I tried to use the two libraries together but it didn't work.
I cannot Paste code and output in comment.

Comment: I added code and output with a guest account

Comment: Create separate instance from libraries and used them

Comment: how do I do this

Comment: There are no changes to the answer

Comment: Please check 3rd code which include `pafy` and `pytube` implementation

Answer (score 0):

````
# import libraries
from pytube import YouTube
import pafy

link ="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_gXTjBZOms"
video = YouTube(link)

# Git video info using pytube
print(f"The video title is:\n{video.title} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video rating is:\n{video.rating} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video Views is:\n{video.views} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video author is:\n{video.author} \n------------------------------")

# Git video info using pafy
print(f"The video duration is:\n{video.duration} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video likes is:\n{video.likes} \n------------------------------")
print(f"The video dislikes is:\n{video.dislikes} \n------------------------------")```
````

Output:

```
The video title is:
كيفيى إضافة عناصر إلى قائمة جديد new في جميع إصدارات windows
------------------------------
The video rating is:
5.0
------------------------------
The video Views is:
48
------------------------------
The video author is:
زينب بهاء
------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\Users\MesterPerfect\Desktop\qais.py", line 17, in <module>
   print(f"The video duration is:\n{video.duration} \n-------------------------
-----")
AttributeError: 'YouTube' object has no attribute 'duration'
```

Answer (score 0):

Dislike No Longer Exist In Youtube, But You Can Use Below Code (With 'pytube' Library) To Get Video Likes:

```
import pytube
import re
def get_likes(pytube_instance):
    like_template = r"like this video along with (.*?) other people"
    text = str(pytube_instance.initial_data)
    matches = re.findall(like_template, text, re.MULTILINE)
    if len(matches) >= 1:
        like_str = matches[0] 
        return int(like_str.replace(',', ''))
    return False

Y = pytube.YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmVrnZAAklU")
print(get_likes(Y))
```